# socket.io emit not working for current user who sends it but working for all other users in the room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a socket running in my node application where I'm emitting an update event that updates the number of users in a room to all the clients. But the problem is that it is updating the count for all the users instead of the user who emitted it. I also want the update for the current user. Here is the code:

```
// emitting to update the poeple count
socket.to(roomId).emit('update-user-count', io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomId).size)

// listening to update the people count
socket.on('update-user-count', (size) => {
  console.log('user count update emitted')
  document.querySelector('.extras--people--count').textContent = `${size} People`
})
```

Comment: From the given code, it seems you haven't added that user to the room with id roomId. 
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.join("some room");
If there is more relevant code please share.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `io.emit()` is the solution to broadcast the message to all the users in a room. More in here: [Broadcasting in Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/broadcasting-events/) [Rooms in Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/)